# Automapper Map class with a constructor that has Dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper

Apologies for this post, I kept googling Automapper and DI and just kept getting IMapper info.

Does automapper support mapping to a class that requires DI parameters in it constuctor? the constructor below with `IWantToBeInjected` is not executed.

```
 public class BO 
    {
        public BO()
        {
            //This gets called
        }

        public BO(IWantToBeInjected fromDI)
        {
            //This doesn't
            FromDI = fromDI;
        }
}

public class MappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BOLike, BO>();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AAutoMapper%2FAutoMapper%20constructusingservicelocator&type=code

Answer (score 0):

It appears if you can tell the map to use `ConstructUsingServiceLocator`

```
public class MappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<BOLike, BO>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
    }
}
```